# Unique permissons for Welcome.aspx

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, permissions, welcome-page

The issue is that I want the welcome page to have different permissions than the remaining pages on the site.  I thought I could break inheritance and then create unique permissions.  After breaking the permissions and changing the groups it affected the entire site.  Is there a way to make the welcome page ONLY unique?

Answer (score 0):

An aspx page is just an item in a list technically so applying unique permissions to this page shouldn't theoratically affect the site permissions. All users will need read permission alteast to the welcome page to be able to access the site. It is like a door to the house. You can use JSOM/REST api on your welcome page to check who the user is or is user in a certain group and redirect different users to different welcome pages if that is what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you @HarryB.  I am trying to achieve where all visitors are able to view the welcome page but not the other pages unless they are in the other permission groups. Maybe I am applying unique permissions incorrectly.  Do I have to break the permissions within designer?

Comment: You can break permissions in the browser using the page permissions button on the ribbon or using the list item menu. Too many unique permissions can make the content difficult to manage. May be you can consider creating subsites for different permission groups rather than applying unique permissions to the pages. That you can have a top site for everyone but subsites with special permissions. part 2 of the comment below!

Comment: Otherwise in your case either re create the site if you can with unique permissions without giving permission to everyone then break inheritance of pages lib then give read access to everyone to the site then grant read access to the welcome page to everyone. or if you cant recreate the site and everyone has access to all the page then you will need to break inheritance for each page and assign unique permissions.